# Placing two numpy arrays in specified order Numpy Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, filter

The function below places the values of numpy arrays `a` and `b` together in accordance to the order of the first column of the 2 dimensional array `indx`. However when I run that it rounds the values of `a` and `b`. I want to keep the values of `a` and `b` as is. how would i be able to do that?

```
import numpy as np 

a= np.array([-1.4545667,-22.44,-3.67,-4.4457,-6.789])
b= np.array([-2.8,-2.54,-6.77,-5.7,-112.9])
indx = np.array([[1, 1010],[0,1212],[1,9000],[0,300],[1,400],[0,640],[1,450],[0,345],[1,344578],[0,232323478]])

d1 = np.nonzero(indx[:, 0])[:len(a)]
d0 = np.nonzero(1-indx[:, 0])[:len(b)] 
loss_combo = np.empty_like(indx[:, 1])

loss_combo[d0] = b
loss_combo[d1] = a
```

Output:

```
[  -1   -2  -22   -2   -3   -6   -4   -5   -6 -112]
```

Expected output:

```
[  1.4545667  -2.8  -22.44  -2.54... -112.9]
```

Comment: What's the `dtype` of the `Output` array.  Looks like it's `integer`?

Comment: yes it outputs an int I want it to output a float

Comment: but you created it **like** an integer array, `indx`!